# Trying to pass a React component to an object, but keep getting A non-serializable value error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I understand what the error means, but despite adding an object to get past the error, it persists.

Note: I'm using Redux Toolkit

This is my drawer Redux file:

```
type InitialState =  {
    isOpen: Boolean,
    shoppingCartItems: {[key:string]:any},
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
    isOpen: false, 
    shoppingCartItems: {},
}

export const drawer = createSlice({
    name:"drawer", 
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        addToCart: (state: any, action: any) => {
            state.shoppingCartItems[action.payload.props.productName] = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export const {addToCart} = drawer.actions;
```

the ProductName is supposed to be the key in the object, and the action.payload is supposed to be the my component. This is how component looks like:

```
 <Button onClick={() => addToShoppingCart(<Product productName={productName} />)}  >Add </Button>
```

the <Product ...> is what I want to store in my redux store, and the addToShoppingcart function looks like so:

```
 function addToShoppingCart(item: any){
      dispatch(addToCart(item))
    }
```

I'm aware that it's not recommended to use a non-serializable value when passing to arrays, but is there a way from the example I gave to avoid the error?

What I've tried:

- Switched from arrays to objects as suggested on a different post
- Stored my component inside a const value

Both did not work.

Comment: What's the reason you want to store a `<Product>` element? Putting elements in state or redux is usually a bad idea. Can you just store the data (the names of the items in your case), and then create the elements from that data when you render?

Comment: Maybe, currently I'm doing it so it appears in my shopping cart, when I press the add button.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems here - one conceptual, and one technical.

The conceptual problem is that **in both React and Redux, state is *data*, made up of plain JS objects and arrays**.  JSX elements like `<MyComponent>` are *not* "data".

JSX elements should be calculated *while rendering in a component*, and that rendering should be based on the actual current state.

The technical issue is that Redux Toolkit is specifically checking for mistakes like this and telling you *not* to do that :)

So, the right answer would be to dispatch an action containing this `item` by itself (or the ID of the item).  Then, read that in the component, and render `<Product>` in the component based on that data.